# Android AsyncTask: "An error occured while executing doInBackground()"

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I'm having a bit of a problem understanding what's happening here, so any help would be very much appreciated. I'm kind of new to the Android development.

Those are the errors I'm receiving:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
              Process: com.example.benignfella.workorganizer, PID: 9956
              java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                  at com.example.benignfella.workorganizer.Fragment.RecordsListFragment$GetRecordsTask.doInBackground(RecordsListFragment.java:87)
                  at com.example.benignfella.workorganizer.Fragment.RecordsListFragment$GetRecordsTask.doInBackground(RecordsListFragment.java:77)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

and here's the class which is apparently problematic (which begins at the line 77, as described by `RecordsListFragment.java:77`)

```
public class GetRecordsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Records>> {

    private final WeakReference<Activity> activityWeakRef;

    public GetRecordsTask(Activity context) {
        this.activityWeakRef = new WeakReference<Activity>(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Records> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        ArrayList<Records> recordsArrayList = recordsDAO.getRecords();
        return recordsArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Records> empList) {
        if (activityWeakRef.get() != null && !activityWeakRef.get().isFinishing()) {
            records = empList;
            if (empList != null) {
                if (empList.size() != 0) {
                    recordsListAdapter = new RecordsListAdapter(activity, empList);
                    recordsListView.setAdapter(recordsListAdapter);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "No Records about records... wait wot m8?",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error points at the `doInBackground` method, more specifically, this line:

```
ArrayList<Records> recordsArrayList = recordsDAO.getRecords();
```

I've read something about conveying block of code to `onPostExecute` method, but I'm not sure how. It'd be great if someone could help me out on that one.

**Edit:** The [proposed thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) did not solve my problem the reason why I'm posting a question is that I'm not able to solve the problem myself.

According to the thread, NPE can occur because I'm *assuming* that object was created before the method was called, but wasn't that what I did here: `public class GetRecordsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Records>>`?

I genuinely do not understand what I'm doing wrong, so I'm really asking for some concrete help.

**Edit 2:** here is the RecordsDAO class in its entirety

```
public class RecordsDAO extends RecordsDBDAO {

    public static final String RECORDS_ID_WITH_PREFIX = "records.id";

    private static final String WHERE_ID_EQUALS = DatabaseHelper.ID + " =?";

    private static final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);

    //Constructor
    public RecordsDAO(Context context) {
    super(context);
    }

    public long save(Records records) {
    //Use ContentValues to access database
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    //Should I add the ID field as well?
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.DESCRIPTION, records.getDescription());
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_CREATED_AT, formatter.format(records.getDateofRecord()));
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.STARTINGHOUR, records.getStart());
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.FINISHINGHOUR, records.getFinish());
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.COMMENTS, records.getComments());

    return database.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_RECORDS, null, values);
    }

    public long update(Records records) {
    //Use ContentValues to access database
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.DESCRIPTION, records.getDescription());
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_CREATED_AT, formatter.format(records.getDateofRecord()));
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.STARTINGHOUR, records.getStart());
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.FINISHINGHOUR, records.getFinish());
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.COMMENTS, records.getComments());

    long result = database.update(
            DatabaseHelper.TABLE_RECORDS,
            values,
            WHERE_ID_EQUALS,
            new String[] {
                    String.valueOf(records.getId())
            }
    );

    return result;
    }

    public int deleteRecord(Records records) {
    return database.delete(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_RECORDS,
            WHERE_ID_EQUALS,
            new String[] {
                    records.getId() + ""
            });
    }

    public ArrayList<Records> getRecords() {
    ArrayList<Records> records = new ArrayList<Records>();

    String query = "SELECT " + RECORDS_ID_WITH_PREFIX + ", "
            + DatabaseHelper.DESCRIPTION + " ,"
            + DatabaseHelper.KEY_CREATED_AT + ", "
            + DatabaseHelper.STARTINGHOUR + ", "
            + DatabaseHelper.FINISHINGHOUR + ", "
            + DatabaseHelper.COMMENTS + " FROM "
            + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_RECORDS + " rec,"
            + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_LOCATIONS + " loc,"
            + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_TAGS + " tg WHERE rec."
            + DatabaseHelper.LOCATIONS_ID + " = loc." + DatabaseHelper.ID + " AND "
            + DatabaseHelper.TAGS_ID + " = tg." + DatabaseHelper.ID;

    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Records records1 = new Records();
        records1.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
        records1.setDescription(cursor.getString(1));

        try {
            records1.setDateofRecord(formatter.parse(cursor.getString(2)));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            records1.setDateofRecord(null);
        }

        records1.setStart(cursor.getString(3));
        records1.setFinish(cursor.getString(4));
        records1.setComments(cursor.getString(5));

        Locations locations = new Locations();
        locations.setId(cursor.getInt(6));
        locations.setLocation(cursor.getString(7));

        Tags tags = new Tags();
        tags.setId(cursor.getInt(8));
        tags.setName(cursor.getString(9));

        records1.setLocations(locations);
        records1.setTags(tags);
        records.add(records1);
    }
    return records;
    }

    public void loadTags() {
    Tags tag = new Tags("Ljubljana, Faculty");
    Tags tag1 = new Tags("Kranj, OpenLab");
    Tags tag2 = new Tags("Ljubljana, Other");
    Tags tag3 = new Tags("Kranj, Other");

    List<Tags> tagsList = new ArrayList<Tags>();
    tagsList.add(tag);
    tagsList.add(tag1);
    tagsList.add(tag2);
    tagsList.add(tag3);

    for (Tags tg : tagsList) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DatabaseHelper.TAGS, tg.getName());
        database.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_TAGS, null, values);
    }
    }
}
```

### Solution

As @Mangal has pointed out, my mistake was in not initializing the `RecordsDAO` in its entirety, hence the Null Pointer Exception. The class which includes `GetRecordsTask` class did declare

```
RecordsDAO recordsDAO;
```

but this is incomplete initialization. In reality, it should be

```
RecordsDAO recordsDAO = new RecordsDAO(getActivity());
```

and **that** solved my issue.
Big thanks for helping me out on that one, problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayList<Records> recordsArrayList = recordsDAO.getRecords();
```

This line is suspicious to me too.
You should've posted the **recordsDAO**'s class too.
I'd suggest you check your recordsDAO's getRecords() method carefully.
I wanted to comment this but I couldn't.

Comment: I have edited my question, would you mind please taking a look at it? The method you are asking, `getRecords()`, is included. The SQLite query that you see is linked to tables created in another class called `DatabaseHelper`. By the way, thank you for responding to my question!

Comment: Problem solved, will edit the thread to include the solution! Thank you so much for pointing out what I should check, it actually helped a lot. I accepted your answer as the solution. Even though it hasn't explicitly pointed out at my mistake, it helped me know what to look for.

Comment: You're welcome.